# Why does Django fail to make directories and open files on production server?

Tags: django, apache, file, file-io

Bringing up a Django site on a production Linux server using Apache with mod_python, I'm running the following code for a file upload:

```
from django.conf import settings
import os

# ...

upload_base_dir = "upload"
file_pointer = files['file']
file_path = os.path.join(settings.ROOT_SITE_DIR, upload_base_dir, event_name)
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    os.makedirs(file_path)
file = open(file_path + '/' + file_name, 'wb+')
for chunk in file_pointer.chunks():
    file.write(chunk)
file.close()
```

The file_path is an absolute path to the file. I've done a little debugging to find that if the file_path doesn't exist, os.makedirs() fails (500 error returned to requester). If the file_path does exist, the file open fails. I've ensured that directory permissions are permissive enough.

The code works when I am running the Django development server. I've used this code before, and it works in other sites. I'm pretty sure the Apache configuration is the same for relevant settings.

Should be a simple fix, so this is driving me crazy. Does anyone have pointers for other things I should check? Can I rule out Apache as part of the issue?

Comment: When the file open fails, what error do you get?

Comment: The requester receives a 500 error, just as when makedirs() is called.

Comment: Anything in the apache error logs? There should be a python exception happening somewhere. How do you know its the file open that fails?

Answer (score 0):

Does os.path.join always leave you a trailing slash on file_path? Because if not, then your open(file_path+file_name) won't have one between them. Try os.path.join on them.

Dunno why it would be different from your development server though...

Comment: Ah, good point. That was just a copy-paste + editing for posting issue. I've edited the original post to reflect the change.

Comment: You should still use os.path.join in case the path does have a slash on it, thus getting two slashes in your final full path. Seeing path+"/"+name makes me twitch!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Apache threads didn't have access to the files because they were spawned under a user (www-data) that wasn't part of the group that owns the directories. Hopefully this can help someone else save time down the road.